# DataFrame (like in R or Pandas) for C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, data-analysis

Is there a C++ library providing a data structure similar to DataFrame from R or Pandas? What I'm mostly interested in is:

- data structure for tabular data, columns can be of different types (float, integer, string,...),
- operations like selecting, filtering, merging, combining, grouping, etc.

Comment: Someone just marked this question as off topic. Why? I would really like to know the reasoning behind that, it puzzles me.

Comment: Because: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.
Maybe ask in the chat instead?

Comment: The problem is as follows: I am developing a system in C++ which deals with tabular data, columns can be of different types. The users should be able to do all sort of analysis/filtering/transformations of the data. It seems to me that DataFrame data structure, known from R and Pandas, would be perfect for this data, BUT I need it for C++, not R or Python. I would have thought that the problem and question is most appropriate for StackOverflow, but it turns out it's not. Weird.

Comment: columns can be of primitive types only? if so you can use a union for with a type id. Most operations you can use by sorting and binary searching i guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also check out the xtensor C++ library which has an API very close to that of **numpy**, and also handles **missing values**.

Bonus point: you can use it to edit numpy arrays inplace. http://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a C++ library *per se* that can do what Pandas can do, but perhaps you might not *want* to use C++ for that. Have you considered using C++/Python bindings? These can facilitate easy transitions from C++ to Python so you can use Pandas dataframes and transition them to C++.

See, for example, Boost.Python: https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python?action=show&redirect=BoostPython

Comment: For future comers... use pybind, it's much much easier to integrate and use, atleast my opinion